# Loopback 4 authorization allowing access to all type of users

Tags: loopback4

I am following [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@loopback/authorization) article for implementing authorization in my app. The user with the admin role can perform certain operations that other users can't.

But it is not working. The controllers are accessible to all type of users

Here is the code

Thank you in advance

user model has a property called role

```
  @property({
    type: 'string',
  })
  role?: string;
```

authorizer.ts

```
import {AuthorizationContext, AuthorizationDecision, AuthorizationMetadata} from '@loopback/authorization';
import {securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
import _ from 'lodash';

// Instance level authorizer
// Can be also registered as an authorizer, depends on users' need.
export async function basicAuthorization(
  authorizationCtx: AuthorizationContext,
  metadata: AuthorizationMetadata,

): Promise<AuthorizationDecision> {

  //console.log(authorizationCtx.principals[0])
  //console.log(authorizationCtx.roles)
  // No access if authorization details are missing
  let currentUser: UserProfile;
  if (authorizationCtx.principals.length > 0) {
    const user = _.pick(authorizationCtx.principals[0], [
      'id',
      'name',
      'role', // propety role
    ]);
    //console.log(user)
    currentUser = {[securityId]: user.id, name: user.name, roles: user.role};

    console.log(currentUser)

  } else {
    return AuthorizationDecision.DENY;
  }

  if (!currentUser.roles) {
    return AuthorizationDecision.DENY;
  }

  // Authorize everything that does not have a allowedRoles property
  if (!metadata.allowedRoles) {
    return AuthorizationDecision.ALLOW;
  }

  let roleIsAllowed = false;
  const role = currentUser.roles
  // for (const role of currentUser.roles) {
  if (metadata.allowedRoles!.includes(role)) {
    roleIsAllowed = true;
    // }
  }

  if (!roleIsAllowed) {
    return AuthorizationDecision.DENY;
  }

  // Admin and support accounts bypass id verification
  if (
    currentUser.roles.includes('admin') ||
    currentUser.roles.includes('support')
  ) {
    return AuthorizationDecision.ALLOW;
  }

  /**
   * Allow access only to model owners, using route as source of truth
   *
   * eg. @post('/users/{userId}/orders', ...) returns `userId` as args[0]
   */
  if (currentUser[securityId] === authorizationCtx.invocationContext.args[0]) {
    return AuthorizationDecision.ALLOW;
  }

  return AuthorizationDecision.DENY;
}
```

application.ts

```
   //Other imports        
        import {MyAuthorizationProvider} from './services/try';
        import {AuthorizationComponent, AuthorizationDecision, AuthorizationOptions, AuthorizationTags} from '@loopback/authorization';

       constructor(options: ApplicationConfig = {}) {
       super(options);
      // other code
        let app = new Application()
    const data: AuthorizationOptions = {
      precedence: AuthorizationDecision.DENY,
      defaultDecision: AuthorizationDecision.DENY,
    };

    const binding = app.component(AuthorizationComponent);
    app.configure(binding.key).to(data);

    app
      .bind('authorizationProviders.my-authorizer-provider')
      .toProvider(MyAuthorizationProvider)
      .tag(AuthorizationTags.AUTHORIZER);
}
```

user.controller.ts

```
  @get('/users/count', {
    responses: {
      '200': {
        description: 'User model count',
        content: {'application/json': {schema: CountSchema}},
      },
    },
  })

  @authenticate('jwt')
  @authorize({allowedRoles: ['admin']})

  async count(
    @param.where(User) where?: Where<User>,
  ): Promise<Count> {
    return this.userRepository.count(where);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The actual problem was while generating the token, property role wasn't included in TokenService from @loopback/authentication.

So I created custom-token service implementing this TokenService and added a property role while token-generation.

So later loopback-authentication sends this role to loopback-authorization. You can access it in AuthorizationContext.principals[0]

Here is the code

custom-toekn.service.ts

```
import {TokenService} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {inject} from '@loopback/context';
import {HttpErrors} from '@loopback/rest';
import {securityId, UserProfile} from '@loopback/security';
import {promisify} from 'util';
import {TokenServiceBindings} from '../keys';

const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const signAsync = promisify(jwt.sign);
const verifyAsync = promisify(jwt.verify);

export class JWTService implements TokenService {
  constructor(
    @inject(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SECRET)
    private jwtSecret: string,
    @inject(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN)
    private jwtExpiresIn: string,
  ) {}

  async verifyToken(token: string): Promise<UserProfile> {
    if (!token) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(
        `Error verifying token : 'token' is null`,
      );
    }

    let userProfile: UserProfile;

    try {
      // decode user profile from token
      const decodedToken = await verifyAsync(token, this.jwtSecret);
      // don't copy over  token field 'iat' and 'exp', nor 'email' to user profile
      userProfile = Object.assign(
        {[securityId]: '', name: ''},
        {
          [securityId]: decodedToken.id,
          name: decodedToken.name,
          id: decodedToken.id,
          role: decodedToken.role,
        },
      );
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(
        `Error verifying token : ${error.message}`,
      );
    }
    return userProfile;
  }

  async generateToken(userProfile: UserProfile): Promise<string> {
    if (!userProfile) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(
        'Error generating token : userProfile is null',
      );
    }
    const userInfoForToken = {
      id: userProfile[securityId],
      name: userProfile.name,
      role: userProfile.role,
    };
    // Generate a JSON Web Token
    let token: string;
    try {
      token = await signAsync(userInfoForToken, this.jwtSecret, {
        expiresIn: Number(this.jwtExpiresIn),
      });
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpErrors.Unauthorized(`Error encoding token : ${error}`);
    }

    return token;
  }
}
```

keys.ts

```
import {TokenService} from '@loopback/authentication';

export namespace TokenServiceConstants {
  export const TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE = 'myjwts3cr3t';
  export const TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN_VALUE = '600';
}

export namespace TokenServiceBindings {
  export const TOKEN_SECRET = BindingKey.create<string>(
    'authentication.jwt.secret',
  );
  export const TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN = BindingKey.create<string>(
    'authentication.jwt.expires.in.seconds',
  );
  export const TOKEN_SERVICE = BindingKey.create<TokenService>(
    'services.authentication.jwt.tokenservice',
  );
}
```

Then you have to bind this token-service in application.ts

application.ts

```
import {JWTService} from './services/token-service';
import {TokenServiceBindings, TokenServiceConstants} from './keys';

this.bind(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SECRET).to(
      TokenServiceConstants.TOKEN_SECRET_VALUE,
    );

    this.bind(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN).to(
      TokenServiceConstants.TOKEN_EXPIRES_IN_VALUE,
    );

    this.bind(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SERVICE).toClass(JWTService);
```

controller.ts

```
import {authenticate, TokenService, UserService} from '@loopback/authentication';
import {Credentials, OPERATION_SECURITY_SPEC, TokenServiceBindings, UserServiceBindings} from '@loopback/authentication-jwt';
import {authorize} from '@loopback/authorization';

export class UserController {
  constructor(
    @repository(UserRepository)
    public userRepository: UserRepository,

    @inject(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SERVICE)
    public jwtService: TokenService,
    @inject(UserServiceBindings.USER_SERVICE)
    public userService: UserService<User, Credentials>,
    @inject(SecurityBindings.USER, {optional: true})
    public users: UserProfile,

  ) {}


@authenticate('jwt')
  @authorize({allowedRoles: ['admin'], voters: [basicAuthorization]})

aasync fund(){}

}
```

Comment: Getting error from this line in application.ts
    this.bind(TokenServiceBindings.TOKEN_SERVICE).toClass(JWTService);

Argument of type 'typeof JWTService' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Constructor<TokenService>'.